# Disabling the self-signed certificate exception for Java

Tags: windows-10, java, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to access a Java Applet over https, the big burden is the applet is self-signed (which I currently have no control over) and the https port changes every time because it is behind a private network and served via a proxy.

Therefore, adding the exception list doesn't work because the port doesn't match (unless I go through and add the thousands of port possibilities for the public IP).

Is there a workaround (without recompiling java) to disable this exception?  Or is there some way to export the certificate from the Java Web Start for me to import it as trusted?

Running latest JRE 8, Windows 10 x64.

Comment: What's the full exception message? I've done something similar before, but it involved a code modification, not just a simple runtime flag. Would depend on which network library it's using.